# Replace numbers by `nan` in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, replace, nan

I have an issue with a column on a pandas data frame. Due to data input errors I have a column with `true` and `false`, but it also contains around 71 decimals.

I am trying to get rid of the decimals and turn them into `nan` so I can ignore those rows for further analysis.

When I try:

```
datafinal['any_misread'] = datafinal['any_misread'].where(datafinal['any_misread'] < 1, np.nan)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

I have also tried logics with `.replace` and with no success.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You have join data type? can you show `datafinal['any_misread'].dtypes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try using `where` and `astype`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[True, False, 0.12, True, False, .3]})

df.where((df.col1.astype(str) == 'True') | (df.col1.astype(str) == 'False'))
```

Output:

```
    col1
0   True
1  False
2    NaN
3   True
4  False
5    NaN
```

Comment: what to do when I need to retain only float values

Comment: @pyd You can use this: `df.where((df.col1.astype(str) != 'True') & (df.col1.astype(str) != 'False'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the type of each item in the column is not a bool and change the value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[True],[True],[False],[10.2],[1.0],[False],[0]], columns=['misread'])
df.misread[df.misread.apply(lambda x: not isinstance(x, bool))] = pd.np.nan

df
# returns
  misread
0    True
1    True
2   False
3     NaN
4     NaN
5   False
6     NaN
```